# How to align y labels in a Seaborn PairGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Taken from the [documentation](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html):

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
>>> iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
>>> g = sns.PairGrid(iris)
>>> g = g.map(plt.scatter)
```

[image: PairGrid]

How can I align y labels?

What I tried:

```
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.yaxis.labelpad = 20
```

However, that only *shifts* all labels by the specified amount instead of aligning them.

Comment: They look aligned enough to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, that alignment is terrible. How dare a package that boasts to make ["attractive statistical graphics"](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/) fail so abysmally at the alignment of labels?! Just kidding, I love me some seaborn, at least for inspiration on how to improve my own plots.

You are looking for:

```
ax.get_yaxis().set_label_coords(x,y) # conveniently in axis coordinates
```

Also, I would only iterate over the axes that show the label, but that is just me:

```
for ax in g.axes[:,0]:
    ax.get_yaxis().set_label_coords(-0.2,0.5)
```

`0.5` for a centred vertical alignment, `-0.2` for a slight offset to the left (trial-and-error).

[image]

Comment: Wow, now that's nice. I found a solution iterating over `g.axes.flat` and then assigning a specific `ax.yaxis.labelpad` per group of axes. However, that's definitely more trial and error than your approach. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If iterating over all axes `g.axes.flatten()` works for me.

```
for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    ax.get_yaxis().set_label_coords(-0.2,0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way:

```py
g.figure.align_ylabels(g.axes.flatten())
```